# Compare enums in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums, comparable, equatable

I have a class that contains two enums like so (made simple):

```
class Errors {
    enum UserError: String {
        case NoToken = "No token!"
        case NoPassword = "No password!"
    }

    enum BackendError: String {
        case NoConnection = "No connection!"
        case ServerBusy = "Server is busy!"
    }
}
```

Now I want to write generic a function, that accepts either an UserError or an BackendError and return a String depending on the input. Something like this:

```
func alert(type: /* Accepts Error.UserError or BackendError*/) -> String {
    // checks if UserError or BackendError and returns .rawValue
}
```

My first approach was to use generics - but frankly, I'm having trouble understanding this concept and I have an inclination I'm fundamentally wrong here. What I did was:

```
func alert<T>(type: T) {
    if type == Errors.UserError {
        return Errors.UserError.NoPassword.rawValue
    } else {
        return Errors.BackendError.NoConnection.rawValue
    }
 }
```

Obviously, this does not work.

```
binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'Errors.UserError.Type'
```

I understand this has something to do with the missing implementation Equatable/Comparable protocols and my general lack of understanding of using generics. My questions are:

1. How can I compare my generic "type" parameter with my enum?
2. Is my understanding of generics totally wrong?

Also: I would like to avoid the `AnyObject` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing your `enums` have in common and that you want to take advantage of is that they are `RawRepresentable` where their `RawValue` type is `String`.

So you need a function like:

```
func alert<T: RawRepresentable where T.RawValue == String>(t: T) -> String {
    return t.rawValue
}
```

Comment: This works, although I will need some more to wrap my head around what actually happens.

Comment: @schnabler yes it's tough to get your head around generics to begin with. The thing I found useful was to think that you're not declaring a single function here but really a whole family of functions, one for each Type that implements RawRepresentable and has a RawValue type of String.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your purpose. I assume you want a generic function can accept either enum also print out each own string. Probably you can take my answer for references.

Function:

```
func alert<T: CustomStringConvertible>(t: T) -> String {
    return t.description
}
```

Enum:

```
    enum UserError: String, CustomStringConvertible {
        case NoToken = "No token!"
        case NoPassword = "No password!"

        var description: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }

    enum BackendError: String, CustomStringConvertible {
        case NoConnection = "No connection!"
        case ServerBusy = "Server is busy!"

        var description: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a generic function there. `func alert(t: CustomStringConvertible) -> String {
    return t.description
}` works fine.

Comment: @MikePollard Please also take a look of my enum too. My purpose is to achieve the idea of protocol orientated. It can have alert function can work with any thing conform to CustomStringConvertible, no mater enum, struct or class

Comment: Yep, just saying that `func alert(t: CustomStringConvertible) -> String { return t.description }` does just that. Takes any `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: while I ended up using @MikePollard's solution, this answer helped me a lot when it comes to understanding protocols.